# Как организовать ввод чисел в массив с клавиатуры

Tags: c++

Сначала скажу , что задание по длинной арифметике . Подскажите как написать цикл по заполнению элементов массива знаками(цифрами) , чтобы можно было написать полностью само число , а не нажимать перед каждой цифрой enter . И после того как число введено , нужно сделать проверку на нажатие какой либо клавиши(enter на пример), чтобы после нее ввод завершился . P.S также чтобы пользователь мог вводить числа не обязательно до конца массива , а сколько необходимо
В программировании новичок , так что не судите строго)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int length, size_a, size_b;
    char s;
    cout << "Enter the size of first array(A) : ..." << '\n';
    cin >> size_a;
    //cout << "Enter the size of second array(B) : ..." << '\n';
    //cin >> size_b;
    char *A = new char[size_a];
    for (int i = 0; i < size_a; i++)
    {

        s = getchar();
        if (s == '\n') break;
        A[i] = s;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size_a; i++)
    {
        cout << A[i] << "\t";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Эмм, а зачем вы взяли мой код и добавили к себе в вопрос? И то не правильно добавили. То что вы написали не будет работать так как нужно. Если у вас есть вопрос к моему ответу, то задайте его и я постараюсь ответить.

Answer (score 0):

Как пример можно использовать функцию `getchar()` из библиотеки `stdio.h`, которая считывает 1 символ из буффера.

Тогда после того, как ввели размер `A` вы нажимаете `enter`, который сначала нужно убрать из буффера и начать считывать само число, пока не дойдем до символа новой строки.

Вот код:

```
//Считываем первый enter из буффера
char s = getchar();
for (int i = 0; i < size_a; i++)
{
    //считываем символ
    s = getchar();
    if(s == '\n') break;
    A[i] = s;
}
```

Comment: Только первый enter может и отсутствовать в буфере. В этом случае проглотится 1-й вводимый символ.